# Detached Criteria | Collection containing Collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

We have 4 Tables,

One A to One B | One B to Many C | One C to Many D

All are configured Bi-directional and Lazy Fetch.

I have created the Detached Criteria based on 'B'. And trying to fetch A eagerly, C eagerly, C.D eagerly.

As you know, C is a Set and D is also a Set in C.

How do i do this? I tried setting fetchmode to EAGER. It didnt work and i am getting LazyInitializationException.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any order that needs to be followed in creating alias, add restrictions, setting fetch mode? when do we need to create alias?

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "_A");

subCriteria.createAlias("_A.B", "_B");
subCriteria.createAlias("_B.C", "_C");
subCriteria.createAlias("_C.D", "_D");
subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("_D.id", 10));
subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("_D.id"));

criteria = subCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(session);

List list = criteria.list();
```